# iAd BannerView実装のビルド時のサイズに関して

Tags: swift, xcode, iad

iAd BannerViewの実装に関してなのですが、iPhone6の画面サイズのStoryboard上にiAd BannerViewを設置をするとサイズ変更が320×50で固定されてしまい、制約をつけて設置し、ビルドしても、画面の右側に寄ってしまい、丁度いい画面サイズに広告が表示されません。
(ちなみにSimulatorの画面サイズもiPhone6です)

また、iAdのframeworkを使ってビルドしてみると勝手にSimulatorに表示されるのですが、
重ねるようにiAd BannerViewを設置しても良いのでしょうか？

(iAd frameworkのコードになります)

```js
import UIKit
import iAd


  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //iAdバーナーの表示
        }
```

また、iAd実装する時にAppDelegateには何も書き込まない状態でいいのでしょうか？？
それもふまえて教えて頂けると幸いです。
ご回答宜しくお願い致します。

【補足】
コメント欄に「どのようにStoryboardに部品を設置しているのか」というご指摘を頂きましたので、補足致しますと、
Storyboardの下部に手動でiAdBannerViewを設置しております。ビルドすると、iPhone6画面の横幅よりもBannerの方が小さいため、正方形ほどの白い余白ができてしまいます。

Comment: 位置ズレの話は、あなたが、どんなauto layout制約子をつけていて、どう、そのviewをどうstoryboardにはりつけているのか、書かないと、お釈迦様でも、回答出来ないでしょう。
　iAd実装だからといって、AppDelegateになにか書かないといけない必要性は、ないはずです。

Comment: 補足をお書き致しました。お読みいただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

とりあえず、bannerViewに、align で、Horizontal Center in Container.
さらに、bannerViewに、Leading Space to SuperView を、ゼロ。　Trailing Space to SuperViewを、ゼロという制約子を、つけてみては、どうですかね。

Comment: 上手く設置できました！ご回答有り難うございました。